# Does not upload file to the server

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a problem with uploading files to the server. I try to upload a PDF file type and content of the $ _FILES variable is as follows.

```
array(1) { ["userfile"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(46) "archive.pdf" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> int(1) ["size"]=> int(0) } }
```

The value of "error" is 1, so that even gets into the directory "tmp" from the server.

The file weighs in at 6.60M. I have checked the PHP directives:

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

Does anyone know why this happens?.

Thank's for help.

Regards!

Comment: You've answered your own question. What, exactly, would you guess `upload_max_filesize` does?

Comment: Someone needs more coffee. :-p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `upload_max_filesize` is 2M. Your file is 6.60M. Increase the `upload_max_filesize` to something greater than 6.60M such as 10M.